# SharePoint 2013 - prevent sitecollecitonimages from showing up in search results

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results

How do we prevent the /SiteCollectionImages/ folder or anything in it from showing up in SharePoint search results?  is there a query i can write for that?

thanks

Comment: I don't have CA in front of me, but in 2010 at least, you could create rules in Search Administration to exclude content, like http://*/SiteCollectionImages/* and they would not be indexed. Is that available in the 2013 CA?

Comment: I figured it out and will post answer in the morning.  Thanks bro for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dove into understanding the query building syntax that comes with SharePoint 2013, which is accessible whenever you edit the SharePoint search results web part.  Here are steps I took to solve my issue.

- From the Search Results web part, enter edit mode
- Click on the button that says “Change Query” to enter the Query
  Builder Tool
- Within the Query Text box, we can use the following (path) syntax to
  disregard any directory or file from being searched…

  -path:https://www.my-share-point-site.com/SiteCollectionImages